# Submitting a form in an iframe with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe, submit

The `iframe` is on the same domain, I tried the following code, but none of it worked:

```
 myframe.document.getElementById("myform").submit();
 parent.top.frames[0].document.forms[0].submit(); 
 myframe.document.getElementById("myform").submit();

 MyIFrame = document.getElementById("myframe");
 myIFrame.getElementById("myform").submit();
```

Update:

This is the HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="530" height="298"
  src="/iframe.php" name="myframe" id="myframe">
  <p>iframes are not supported by your browser.</p>
</iframe><br />

<form action="/styles.css" method="post" id="form1">
<input type="text" name="input1" value=""/>
<input type="text" name="input2" value=""/>
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="submitFrame()">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<script>

function submitFrame(){

var MyIFrame = document.getElementById("myframe");
var MyIFrameDoc = (MyIFrame.contentWindow || MyIFrame.contentDocument);
if (MyIFrameDoc.document) MyIFrameDoc = MyIFrameDoc.document;
MyIFrameDoc.getElementById("myform").submit(); // ## error 

}


</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

iframe.php:

```
<form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" id="myform" name="myform" action="/"  >

<input type="text" name="input1" value="2073809442" />
<input type="text" name="input2" value="1" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

Firebug says:

```
 MyIFrameDoc.getElementById("myform").submit is not a function
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
var MyIFrame = document.getElementById("myframe");
var MyIFrameDoc = (MyIFrame.contentWindow || MyIFrame.contentDocument);
if (MyIFrameDoc.document) MyIFrameDoc = MyIFrameDoc.document;
MyIFrameDoc.getElementById("myform").submit();
```

**UPDATE**

<strike>I can't figure out why this doesn't work, but here is something that does:</strike>

```
MyIFrameDoc.getElementById("mybutton").click();
```

iframe.php:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="mybutton" />
```

**UPDATE 2**

The reason you're getting the `submit is not a function` error is because you've named your submit button `submit`, so `MyIFrameDoc.getElementById("myform").submit` actually references an `HTMLInputElement`, not the `HTMLFormElement.submit()` method.

All you need to do is rename your submit button, e.g.:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="submit" />
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting an error on submit(); I updated my post with code :)

Comment: Thanks man, I added id and name to the button, but I get MyIFrameDoc.getElementById("mybutton") is null

Comment: @Kristian Did you add an `id` to the button on the parent page or the iframe, cause you're supposed to add it to the button on the iframe page. Also, make sure you've changed the submit event to click event.

Comment: I'm a dumbass :p I added it on the page instead of the iframe, now it works perfectly, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

**Submit the Iframe's URL from javascript**

```
   if (window.parent.$("#IframeId").length > 0) {
        window.parent.$("#IframeId")[0].contentDocument.forms[0].submit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to post into iframe. You can use normal blank "visible" window. Define your form like this:

```
var request = document.createElement("FORM")
request.id = "request"
request.name = "request"
request.action = "callYour.php"
request.method = "POST"
request.target = "_blank"
```

and in your php, when you are done just close the window by:

```
window.close();
```

within the HTML part, or within embedded script tags. The new window temporarily opens up but closeses itself when it is completed.