# How do I make the form only submit to iframe being used

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have a jquery date picker :

```
<script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      });
</script>
```

On my home page that I need to submit the date, to the iframe that the user has currently selected via the radio buttons.

```
<div class="logins_details_container"><!--The top container-->
                <iframe id="iframe" src="math_iframe.php" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>  
        <div class="iframe_container">
            <form>
        <input type="radio" name="iframe" value="type" checked="checked" onclick = "go('math_iframe.php')"/>Maths<br>
        <input type="radio" name="iframe" value="type" onclick = "go('ict_iframe.php')"/>ICT
           </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure your question makes sense as written. Can you please clarify what you need to accomplish?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submitting formin an iframe with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259843/submitting-formin-an-iframe-with-javascript)

Comment: @Blazemonger sorry about that. I need the form to submit to the page that the user has selected in the iframe

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of `#datepicker` from parent in iframe you can use

```
$("#datepicker", window.parent.document).val();
```

Comment: please add some explanation of your code, and specifically how it solves the problem.