# Submit form in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have iframe, in the site is form (post) with button type submit

I want like something:

```
iframe.form.submit()
```

This not work - `$("#iframeid").contents().find("form").submit();`

How to do?

Thanks

Comment: If the iframe is yours, move it's contents to the main page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submitting formin an iframe with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259843/submitting-formin-an-iframe-with-javascript)

Comment: not sure what exactly you are trying to do with facebook, but it does sound like you want to "autoshare" something (since you mentioned share in the comments), which is definitely not allowed. just saying, if that´s the case.

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript solution:

```
var MyIFrame = document.getElementById("iframeid");
var MyIFrameDoc = (MyIFrame.contentWindow || MyIFrame.contentDocument);
if (MyIFrameDoc.document) MyIFrameDoc = MyIFrameDoc.document;
MyIFrameDoc.getElementById("CHANGE TO THE FORM ID").submit();
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: MyIFrameDoc.getElementsByTagName(...).submit is not a function

Comment: My code shows `MyIFrameDoc.getElementById("CHANGE TO THE FORM ID")` not `getElementsByTagName`, correct the code to match mine.